# Expo router.push() pushes slow and I get flashes between screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I am using Expo React to select an image from the image gallery or take a picture using the camera, send the image to an API and wait for the API's response.

Home:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={logo} style={styles.img} />
      {/*Open the image gallery*/}
      <OpenGallery />
      {/*Open the camera */}
      <OpenCamera />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Let's take OpenGallery for example, because the logic is almost identical for the OpenCamera as well:

```
import BTN from "components/layout/BTN";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import { router } from "expo-router";

const OpenGallery = () => {
  const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      aspect: [1, 1],
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      const image = result.assets[0];

      router.push({
        pathname: "/preview",
        params: {
          imageUri: image.uri,
          imageHeight: image.height,
          imageWidth: image.width,
        },
      });
    } else {
      // alert("You did not select any image.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <BTN label="Choose a photo" icon={"picture-o"} onPress={pickImageAsync} />
  );
};

export default OpenGallery;
```

When an image is selected I use router.push to navigate to the Preview Screen.
The issue happens here: when the image is selected and the `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync` finishes, I get a flash of the HomeScreen before the router pushes the Preview Screen and the screen changes. **How can I avoid that flashing ?**

PreviewScreen :

```
const PreviewScreen = () => {
  const params = useLocalSearchParams();
  const [compressedImage, setCompressedImage] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const selectedImage = {
    uri: params.imageUri,
    width: params.imageWidth,
    height: params.imageHeight,
  };

  const onCompressImage = async () => {
    setCompressedImage(await compressImage(selectedImage));
  };
  const onChangeImage = () => router.replace("/");

  if (!selectedImage.uri)
    return (
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>No image to preview</Text>
        <BTN label={"Go back"} onPress={() => router.replace("/")} />
      </View>
    );

  const reset = () => {
    setCompressedImage(null);
    setError(null);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <Image source={{ uri: selectedImage.uri }} style={styles.selectedImage} />
      {compressedImage && !error ? (
        <ResultBox image={compressedImage} error={error} setError={setError} />
      ) : (
        <>
          <ErrorModal visible={error} reset={reset} />
          <BTN label={"Send Image"} onPress={onCompressImage} icon={"send"} />
          <BTN label={"Change Image"} onPress={onChangeImage} />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PreviewScreen;
```

Router's `_layout.js` :

```js
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#f4511e",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{ headerTitle: "Home", headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="preview" options={{ headerTitle: "Preview" }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="result" options={{ headerTitle: "Result" }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```